# How do I round number from 15 digits after decimal point to 6 in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I need to round 41.800000000000004 to 41.8000000

I tried 'convert to number' but it outputs the same, there is no 'convert to float' and 'convert to integer' will delete the decimals

I think it might be possible with 'format string' or some sort of string length manipulation but I'm unsure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see, the value 41.8 seems the correct float representation of your number rounded to 6 decimal points.

To keep trailing zeros, you need to use string format, as they, not meaningful zeros, disappear in float representation.

As one of the options, you could use [string Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

As Robot Framework line:

`evaluate  '{0:.6f}'.format(41.800000000000004)`

--> '41.800000'